# Can server side loop be done in javascript/ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I loop server side code on the client without javascript? I have this loop in my rails app

```
//partial = _manufacturers
<div id="all_manufcaturers">
<% for manufacturers in @manufacturerss%>
  ID: <%= h manufacturers.id %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

How can I render this using ajax? I know something like the following works since it is just a static replacement:

```
$("#manufacturers_count").html('Manufacturer - <%= @car.manufacturers.count %>');
```

But pseudocode like this does not work since the partial contains a loop:

```
$("#all_manufacturers").html('...render(manufacturers)...');
```

Comment: 'without javascript'? But you show an example of jQuery...

Comment: the ajax above is an illustration that does not work, hence a workaround the limitations of js

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done. You will want to make a server side script (e.g php) that builds a dataset for you and echos it with json_encode. You will then want to parse the response from the request with the appropriate javascript decode function in whatever library you're using (example, jQuery.decodeJSON()). You can then loop through the response set and render.

Comment: I've come across this method but i'm wondering about the efficiency of sending all the data to the client?

Comment: Not sure... hrm will look into this more

Comment: This is the basic concept behind AJAX. Send down what you need in the client, of course.